# A validationError when I upgrade webpack from v4 to v5

Tags: webpack

when I update my webpack from 4 to 5, error message give me when I try to npm run dev:

```
/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:105
    throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
    ^

ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].issuer has an unknown property 'test'. These properties are valid:
   object { and?, not?, or? }
   -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    at validate (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:105:11)
    at validateSchema (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/lib/validateSchema.js:78:2)
    at create (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:111:24)
    at webpack (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:158:32)
    at f (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:58:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/james/htdocs/pearl-wrapper/server.js:58:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
```

my webpack.config.json:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.jsx?$/
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [
                  {
                    removeViewBox: false
                  },
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition, passing your RegExp to `issuer` may fix this.

change this

```
issuer: {
      test: /\.jsx?$/
    },
```

to this

```
issuer: /\.jsx?$/,
```